# Server Error TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'key') i18n/graphql-dictionary-service.js

Tags: jss, graphql, nextjs

I am running Sitecore 10 locally with Next.js
The site works fine in Experience Editor but in normal mode i.e. http://localhost:3000/ I started getting this error below. Tried everything but in vain, there is no clue on the console either. Would appreciate quick help

```
Server Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'key')

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Call Stack
<unknown>
file:///C:/sitecore/src/rendering/node_modules/@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss/dist/cjs/i18n/graphql-dictionary-service.js (106:57)
Array.forEach
<anonymous>
<unknown>
file:///C:/sitecore/src/rendering/node_modules/@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss/dist/cjs/i18n/graphql-dictionary-service.js (106:25)
runMicrotasks
<anonymous>
processTicksAndRejections
node:internal/process/task_queues (96:5)
```

Comment: Are you seeing this on every page?  Or just for a specific dictionary entry ? You can try republishing and restarting your rendering host to avoid probability of cache causing this issue.

Comment: @Zaheer Tariq This looks like a graphql error on next.js side. Did you run npm run graphql:update in your next.js application? Also, execute npm run build after that so you have the build utilizing the latest graphql changes.